# Formula to maintain distance along the x-axis between an outer object and an inner object while scaling

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, education

Formula to maintain distance along the **x-axis between an outer object and an inner object** while scaling:

```
Outer cube dimensions = x=4.4, y=11.4, z=11
Inner cube dimensions = x=2.64, y=9.48, z=16.8
```

**Example:**

I have an object I would like to **maintain a constant distance of 0.88** if scaled along the **x-axis**.

[image: img1]

If I scale the object **along the x-axis 3 times** it gives me this.

see image below:

[image: img2]

I'm trying to get cube / object along the **x-axis** to maintain the distance (**in this example it's 0.88**).

[image: img3]

[image: img4]

**When I do this graphically** it comes out the scale I should use to change the x-axis of the outer box should be **0.7339**...**How can I do this using a formula / equation?**

**I'm looking for a formula / equation** due to the fact that this is going to be used to make "parametric" objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to scale the $\ x$-dimension of the inner object by a scale factor $\ s\ $, and keep the $\ x$-distance between the surfaces of  the inner and outer objects fixed at $\ d\ $.

Let $\ w\ $ be the $\ x$-width of the inner object before scaling.  Then the $\ x$-width of the outer object will be $\ w+2d\ $.  *After* scaling, the $\ x$-width of the inner object will be $\ sw\ $, and the $\ x$-width of the outer object will have to be $\ sw+2d $.  The outer object will thus have been scaled in the $ x$-direction by the factor
$$
f=\frac{sw+2d}{w+2d}\ ,
$$
and if you've already scaled the outer object instead by the factor $\ s\ $, then you'll have to rescale it by the factor $\ \frac{f}{s}\ $ to obtain the right dimensions.

In your example, $\ w=2.64,$$\,d=0.88\ ,$ and $\ s=3\ $, and if we plug these into the above formula, we get
$$
f=\frac{3\times2.64+2\times0.88}{2.64+2\times0.88}=\frac{11}{5}
$$

Thus, after scaling the outer box up by a factor of $\ 3\ $, you need to  rescale it by the factor $\ \frac{11}{15}\approx0.7333\ $ to get the right dimensions.  I assume the digit $9$ appearing in the fourth decimal place of the scaling factor $\ 0.7339\dots\ $ you give is either a typo or rounding error.

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly!!!